# JPA persistence.xml flushmode with Hibernate 3.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I understand that Hibernate uses transparent write behind by default for committing the transactions.

However, I would like my entity-manager to commit my transaction on the database immediately after the transaction is committed. Is there anyway I can configure this in persistence.xml of JPA ?

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what "transactional write behind" means.  It does not mean Hibernate delays committing the transaction.  It means instead that Hibernate delays performing INSERTS, UPDATES and DELETES until a later point in time (usually transaction commit).  This process of performing INSERTS, UPDATES and DELETES is called flushing.  So are you really wanting to force Hibernate to not delay flushing maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate would have to commit in the database at the time is made commits the transaction. You can also find it helpful to have two additional options:

- Define the Session and autocommit (entering the property "hibernate.connection.autocommit" in the properties of the connection)
- Forcing hibernate transaction synchronize with the database transaction in the middle of the transaction (by session.flush ())

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to do it without session.flush() because it needs to be done at all places. I tried the first approach and it does not seem to work

Comment: As I mentioned, it is strange that the default does not work, you can also force the FlushMode session as follows "session.setFlushMode (FlushMode.ALWAYS)" if it works I recommend you consider whether to "FlushMode.COMMIT" have enough